# Find a formula for the number of functions $f$ from $P_k$ to {$1, . . . , n$} such that $f(A ∪ B)$ = the larger of the two integers $f(A)$ and $f(B)$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $P_k$ denote the set of all subsets of {$1, . . . , k$}. Find a formula for the number of
functions $f$ from $P_k$ to {$1, . . . , n$} such that $f(A ∪ B)$ = the larger of the two integers $f(A)$
and $f(B)$. Your answer need not be a closed formula but it should be simple enough to use
for given values of $n$ and $k,$ e.g., to see that for $k = 3$ and $n = 4$ there are $100$ such functions.

I'm unable to understand the question. Please help.

Comment: What part of the question do you not understand?

Comment: @Watercrystal I don't understand the part where it says $P_k$ to {$1,..., n$}. How would the set of all subsets map to a particular set, and what do I consider it to be to solve the problem? I also don't understand how we define f(A U B), as in, what exactly is the input?

Comment: A function from $P_k$ to $\{1, ..., k\}$ takes a subset of $\{1, ..., k\}$ and maps it to a number in $\{1, ..., k\}$. A set is just another kind of mathematical object, like a number, so a function mapping sets to numbers isn't illegal or something.

Now, the result of taking the union of two sets is a set again, so it makes sense to talk about $f(A \cup B)$ in the same way it makes sense to talk about $g(a + b)$ for a function mapping numbers to numbers.

Comment: @Watercrystal so $f$ takes values from the domain which is a set and hence we're taking about A U B but then what the function maps to, i.e., $f(A)$ or $f(B)$ is also a function with a set as the input so how exactly do we get a number as the output?

Comment: Side note: you can write $\cup$ using `\cup`. The domain of a function is always* as set, but in this specific instance the domain is a set _of sets_. That is what $P_k$, the power set of $\{1, ..., k\}$ is. If $A$ is a set, $f(A)$ is a number. The text then states that $f(A \cup B) = \max \{f(a), f(b)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As  Watercrystal observed, you are asking is the number of monoid morphisms form the monoid $(P_k, \cup)$ to the monoid $(\{1, \ldots, n\}, \max)$. Both monoids are idempotent and commutative and $P_k$ is the free idempotent and commutative monoid on $k$ generators. It means that a monoid morphism $f: (P_k, \cup) \to (\{1, \ldots, n\}, \max)$ is uniquely and entirely determined by the values of $f$ on the singletons of $P_k$. Since there are $n$ possibilities for each singleton, the number of morphisms is $n^k$. For $n = 4$ and $k = 3$ you get $4^3 = 64$ (and not $100$) such morphisms.

**EDIT**. Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_r\}$  be a subset of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$. Since $A = \{a_1\} \cup \ldots \cup \{a_r\}$, one gets
$$
f(A) = \max \bigl\{f(\{a_1\}), f(\{a_2\}), \ldots, f(\{a_r\})\bigr\}
$$
Thus the value of $f(A)$ is determined by the values of $f(\{i\})$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$. There are $n$ possible choices for the value of each $f(\{i\})$ and hence $n^k$ possibilities for $f$.

**EDIT**. This answer only works for nonempty subsets. See the other answer for a complete solution.

Comment: I don't understand, I'm meant to solve this using only high school mathematics.

Comment: What about the empty set? It could go to any point less or equal to the lowest number in the image of the singletons, I think.

Comment: @Tapi the idea is that such function is determined by its values on singletons {j}, and can can arbitrarily assigned to the $k$ singletons ... except the empty set must also be mapped and the number of choices for it depends on the singleton assignments (or vice verse) which is why it’s not as simple as $n^k$.

Comment: @Ned okay so do we reach that conclusion by applying the function over and over again, like say $f( A \cup B)=f(A)$ and then we see $A=C \cup D$ and apply it again until we can't apply it anymore? Is that why we reach a place where $A=A \cup \phi$ ( the empty set)?

Comment: Yes, the answer to the question is not $n^k$.

Comment: @Ned You are right, my argument only works if $P_k$ is the set of nonempty subsets of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$.

Comment: I will write a new answer separately, in order to keep these comments available.

Comment: @Tapi yes you can write every non empty set as a union of singletons, the only choices are what to assign to the singletons and the empty set. But every subset equals itself union the empty set, so the number assigned to the empty set must less than or equal to all the singleton assignments.

Comment: I think it should be $n^k + (n-1)^k + ... + 2^k + 1$ by first assigning the empty set and then counting each case from there by the same the idea as in this answer.

Comment: This is what I am writing in my new answer.

Comment: @Ned so $f( A \cup B)$ translates to max{$ f({a_1})...f({a_k}), f( { \phi}))$}. I don't understand why $f( \phi )$ can't be greater or somewhere in between the other values of singleton sets.

Comment: Because f({a}) =  f( empty U {a}) = max ( f(empty, f({a}) ) so f(empty) can't be bigger than f({a}).

Answer (score 0):

In this question, the empty set has to be considered separately. Let $P'_k$ be the set of nonempty subsets of $\{1, \dots, k\}$, let
$$
  m(f) = \min \{f(A) \mid A \in P'_k \}
$$
and let $A$ be a nonemptyset such that $f(A) = m(f)$.
Since
$$
m(f) = f(A) = f(A \cup \emptyset) = \max(f(A), f(\emptyset)) = \max(m, f(\emptyset))
$$
one gets necessarily $f(\emptyset) \leqslant m(f)$.

Moreover, $f$ has to be a semigroup morphism from the semigroup $(P'_k, \cup)$ to the semigroup $(\{1, \ldots, n\}, \max)$. Both semigroups are idempotent and commutative and $P'_k$ is the free idempotent and commutative semigroup on $k$ generators. It means that $f$ is uniquely and entirely determined by the values of $f$ on the singletons of $P'_k$. Indeed, if $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_r\}$  is a subset of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$, one has
$$
f(A) = \max \bigl\{f(\{a_1\}), f(\{a_2\}), \ldots, f(\{a_r\})\bigr\}
$$
Now there are $(n-m+1)^k$ semigroup morphisms from $P'_k$ to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $m \leqslant m(f)$, since the image of such a function is a subset of $\{m, \ldots, n\}$. Among them, there are $(n-m+1)^k - (n-m)^k$ functions such that $m = m(f)$.

For each such function, one can choose for $f(\emptyset)$ any value $\leqslant m$. Altogether we get
\begin{align}
(n^k - (n-1)^k) + 2((n-1)^k - (n-2)^k) + 3 ((n-2)^k - (n-3)^k) + \dotsm + 1^k \\
= n^k + (n-1)^k  + (n-2)^k + \dotsm + 1^k
\end{align}
For $n = 4$ and $k = 3$ you get $4^3 + 3^3 + 2^3 + 1^3 = 64 + 27 + 8 + 1 = 100$.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could make it a bit simpler because I don't understand semigroups or morphisms.